# What is the difference between isPlaying() and isLooping() when using MediaPlayer?

Tags: android

MediaPlayer has been used to play a song using service. In the following code or in general, what is the difference between `isPlaying()` and `isLooping()`?

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (!player.isLooping()){     //isLooping() used
        player.start();
    }
    Toast.makeText(this,"onStartCommand",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(this,"onDestroy",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if (player.isPlaying()){      //isPlaying() used
        player.stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[**`isPlaying()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying())

- Checks whether the `MediaPlayer` is playing.
- Returns `true` if currently playing, `false` otherwise

[**`isLooping()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isLooping())

- Checks whether the `MediaPlayer` is looping or non-looping
- Returns  `true` if the `MediaPlayer` is currently looping, `false` otherwise

Comment: what does playing and looping mean?

Answer (score 0):

Looping here means to play the media in a loop, over and over again. So the media could be playing in a loop or not, that is, it finishes after the first run.